# LINQ expression node type is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I get an error when I try to run the following query in LINQ to Entities:

```
 var query = DBConn.myView
                            .Select(dm => new App.DTOs.MyDTO
                            {
                                ID = dm.ID,
                                Prop1 = dm.Prop1
                                ....
                            })
                            .Where(dm => dm.TypeID != 4);
```

The Error message is:

```
LINQ expression node type 'TypeID' is not supported in LINQ to Entities
```

It fails on the `.ToList()` call:

```
private List<MyDTO> lstDTO;
lstDTO = query.ToList();
```

However, if I remove the `.Where()` from the query, it works. Is there any way to use the `Where` clause with this query?

Comment: Not sure if this question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392612/convert-datatable-to-ienumerablet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to swap your `Select` and `Where` part around:

```
var query = DBConn.myView
              .Where(dm => dm.TypeID != 4)
              .Select(dm => new App.DTOs.MyDTO
                            {
                                ID = dm.ID,
                                Prop1 = dm.Prop1
                                ....
                            });
```