# List<List<String>> to datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a list with lists of strings representing the rows and collumns that I like to show in my datagrid. The number of strings in each row doesn't have to be constant, so say that the list can look something like this:

1. Test, Test, Test
2. Test, Test,
3. Test, Test, Test, Test

I would like make it so that this generates 4 collumns, where the 2 shorter rows leave the last collumns empty. I have tried to set the DataContext to the list objet, but that didn't seem like to way to go...

Anyone have any idea how this could be done?

Comment: The nested ItemControls from @il_agent look good. For a real DataGrid solution, see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/676530/ . A lot more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a class with 4 fields like

```
public class Data{
   public string Field1{get;set;}
   public string Field2{get;set;}
   public string Field3{get;set;}
   public string Field4{get;set;}
}
```

Example would be like this

```
var ls = new List<Data>();
// Fill your data in `List<List<string>>` to ls
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGrid.ItemSource = ls;
```

**EDIT**

I had a look of DataGrid, it seems that there is no support for this kind of binding.

I came up with other solution with help from [Dynamically Add C# Properties at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime)

I would like to see if there is any other better way as well.

```
    var list = new List<List<string>>
    {
        new List<string> {"Test", "Test", "Test"},
        new List<string> {"Test", "Test", ""},
        new List<string> {"Test", "Test", "Test", "Test"}
    };

    var maxLength = list.Max(c => c.Max(r => r.Length));

    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        ResulDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Field" + i, Binding = new Binding("Row" + i) });
    }

    foreach (var listItem in list)
    {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listItem.Count; i++)
        {
            properties.Add("Row" + i, listItem[i]);

        }
        var myObject = GetDynamicObject(properties);
        ResulDataGrid.Items.Add(myObject);
    }

public static dynamic GetDynamicObject(Dictionary<string, object> properties)
        {
            var dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                dynamicObject.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }
            return dynamicObject;
        }
```

Comment: That would work for only 4 fields, the problem here is that it can be 4 fields or 22 fields, I don't know this from the start...

Answer (score 1):

I think with DataGrid you can't do it. Or it will be very difficult and not trivially. Instead of DataGrid you can use nested ItemsControls. Something like that:

```
   <ItemsControl  ItemsSource = {Binding MyList}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>


   <ItemsControl ItemsSource = {Binding}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text = {Binding}/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I hope it will help you.