# Get reference to inner dynamic expandoobject property and add new property for it

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, expandoobject

I'm creating `List<ExpandoObject>`, against a `List<SomeClassA>`. i.e, dynamically creating object using expadoObject, and adding properties to it. I could easily get the required output, but my solution fails if `List<SomeClassA>` has some complex properties, i.e, `Address` field, etc. (for sample example

```
class SomeClassA
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   string Age { get; set; }
   Address address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
   string house { get; set; }
   string city { get; set; }
}
```

Which means for any item in `List<SomeClassA>`, there must me a property like `address.house`. Since i'm in a loop, and property to be mapped can be either simple, or complex (like address). To handle this, i applied a check to know if it's a nested property, and created new expanoObject as dynamic, instead of simple property. something like:

```
//assume:
string name = classAobj.Name; string address = classAobj.Address;
dynamic dynObj = new ExpandoObject();
var prop = dynObj as IDictionary<string, object>;
```

in loop, if the property is simple (eg, name):

```
prop[name] = classAobj.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(classAobj);
```

if property is complex (eg, address):

```
prop[address] = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
//then add its properties. but can't
```

the point where i'm stuck is, i'm unable to get reference of this point: `prop[address]`

**Question** is: how can i access this point and add properties to it dynamically, (i.e, house, city).
`PropertyInfro x = prop.GetType().GetProperty(address);` or `FieldInfo f = prop.GetType().GetField(address);` returns null. While i can see it as `new ExpandoObject` in debugging mode.
[image: Debugging mode: assume 10th location is address]

**Question Summary**: How can i refer to dynamically created **nested** ExpandoObject, and add properties to it. the way i am adding simple properties to outer object.
I'd been through several SO posts, but nothing helped as scenario was always different.

Comment: Is your question [how to add properties to a dynamic object at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime)? If not, can you try to reformat your question a bit, as your actual question isn't very clear to me at least.

Comment: so what happens when you try `prop[address].house = "foo";` ?

Comment: @Selman22 compiler says `object doesn't contain definition for house....`

Comment: @CodeCaster No, it's not my question. if you see in attach image, prop is an expandoobject, i created dynamically. elements from 1 to 9 are properties that i added to an expandoObject.  10th element is an expandoObject, iside another expendoObject (think of address in classA). now i want to set properties for this inner object. How can i refer to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. instead of `PropertyInfro x = prop.GetType().GetProperty(address);`, simply using `prop[address]` was enough for reference. so, following is how it worked.

```
dynamic complexProp = prop[address];
var innerProp = complexProp as IDictionary<string, object>;
innerProp[house] = "some value";
innerProp[city] = "some value";
```

Comment: the cast of complexProp to IDictionary<string, object> fails. So this doesn't work