# How to dynamically override all properties of dynamic object?

Tags: c#

I have two dynamic objects and I'd want to overwrite values of object A with values of object B

The problem is that both are of type `dynamic`

I managed to extract names of the properties with

`TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(oldObject);`

but I'm not sure how can I read & set dynamic property of dynamic object

something like `oldObject.GetType().GetProperty("Test")` won't work since even `GetType().GetProperties()` return empty collection

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override get accessor of a dynamic object's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923280/how-to-override-get-accessor-of-a-dynamic-objects-property) I guess, that you should inherit `DynamicObject` and override its members

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Those objects & their classes are external, I'm unable to modify them

Comment: Although not a satisfying answer, `dynamic` mostly points to a design issue somewhere else. I'd first look at the design reasons for the use of dynamic, before pushing the problem down the road

Answer (score 0):

Below way you can get all the properties and their values.

```
dynamic dynamicObj = //define it
object obj = dynamicObj;
string[] propertyNames = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
foreach (var name in propertyNames)
{
    object value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Use this for private fields.

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Comment: Unfortunely `propertyNames` is also empty :P damn those dynamics

Comment: then I think you debug and check the dynamic object, does it really have properties?

Comment: I used your code, with the only difference at `dynamicObj = myDynamicObj`

Comment: Yea, in `Watch Window` I'm able to see it's properties like `myDynamic.Id` = `800`

Comment: Are these properties `public`?

Comment: Oh, as I see they have no access modifier defined, so they're all private. Btw. Here's pic of how does it look like: https://i.imgur.com/snsTOY6.png

Comment: Its returns all the public properties

Comment: Unfortunely, the result is the same - empty array of prop names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215982/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-joelty).