# C#: Dynamic load a string list to be public properties of a class when app luanch

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, load

I have class like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have another string list from somewhere and want to load it dynamically to be the public properties of `Class1` when my application launch, how can i do?

string list like:

- Email
- Telephone
- Homepage

load them as public properties of `Class1` in run time.

Comment: attempt to solve by the use of code....

Comment: Take a look at dynamic objects or at reflection.

You can use some external library for quick start. Like one decribed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime

Comment: What do you mean with "another string list" and how would you want to map what is in a list of strings to the properties of (an) instance(s) of `Class1` ? What are you trying to achieve. Please [edit] your question to add the relevant details. Currently your question is unclear. Please refer to  [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

If you want to have this dynamic properties in addition to the non-dynamic properties, [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Feb/08/Creating-a-dynamic-extensible-C-Expando-Object) is an article explaining how to create a dynamic object yourself.