# Add Update Delete in Tree Like Collection

Tags: c#, tree

I have a tree stucture like this

```
public class CustomObject
    {
        public int Property1{get;set;}
        public string Property2{get;set;}
        public bool IsTrue{get;set;}
        public List<CustomObject> Items{get;set;}
    }
```

Now I have Collection like List and I want create a new collection from this where IsTrue == true.

Secondly I need to add new Property to the stucture at specific node and similary delete and Update the nodes.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: IsTrue is a propoerty

Comment: You should add some mock code to explain what exactly you are trying to do. The second part of the question is a bit vague too.

Comment: Suppose i have collection like this

Item1 ---> First Item In Collection
  Item11 -----> Fisrt Item1 Collection
  Item12 -----> Second Item1 Collection
   Item21 ----> First item in Item2 Collection and so on
   Item23
Item2 ---> Second item in collection
...
So On


I want to add items at any one of the nodes or update any node and so on

Comment: Yes, that part is mentioned in the question. Now what do you want to do with that collection? Whats stopping you from Deleting / Updating the Nodes? What's the problem? You got a List<> of your Elements. Lists support _Remove_. The Values are not readonly properties so updating shouldn't be a problem either.

Answer (score 0):

First

> Now I have Collection like List and I want create a new collection from this where IsTrue == true.

```
var listWithIsTrueOnly = ListCustomObject.Where(x => x.IsTrue).ToList()
```

And now for your list you can use Add, AddRange, Remove, RemoveAt ...

But still something curious. In your object, you have a list of object. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Items.Where(x => x.IsTrue).ToList().

Over the list you can perform crud operations.

If you want to add an extra property at specific node, I suggest you consider to use an ExpandoObject instead, so you can add or remove the properties at runtime.

Check this links :

[Dynamically Add C# Properties at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx