# Creating class members during run time - C#

Tags: c#

I have a simple class defined like this:

```
public class StickColumns
{
    public string wellname { get; set; }
    public double WellLength { get; set; }
}
```

In the code, I get some data as `list<double> perfdepth`; assume this is `perfdepth1,perfdepth2,perfdepth3`. Of course, this list is dynamic hence, I wouldnt know beforehand to change my class definition to:

```
 public class StickColumns
 {
     public string wellname { get; set; }
     public double WellLength { get; set; }
     public double perfdepth1 { get; set; }
     public double perfdepth2 { get; set; }
     public double perfdepth3 { get; set; }
 }
```

Can these new members be created during run time?
The reason why I think I would need this is because of data binding in WPF. Eventually I need to display "point series"; Perfdepth1 as one series, perfdepth2 as another series and so on, i.e, dynamic number of Perfdepths.

If there is a simpler way to do it, I am all ears!

Comment: While this is certainly possible, this is a much harder way to go about this. I suggest another approach, maybe use a List<double>?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime?

Comment: Please, have a look at `ExpandoObject` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @FailedUnitTest: Each member is to be used as series.Valuememberpath in the WPF data binding that's why. List<double> will not work there.

Comment: @user7157732 chances are for everything your attempting to do, you can substitute with a dictionary<string, object>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might just want to use the dynamic type with `ExpandoObject`..

```
dynamic stickColumns = new ExpandoObject();
stickColumns.wellName  = "Something";
stickColumns.perfdepth1 = "Something Else";
```

It has its drawbacks as it does mean you end up with runtime errors etc... but it can be useful for this type of scenario.

Comment: thnx. Can this be then used in an observable collection<stickColumns>?

Comment: well it would be observablecollection<dynamic> or object but would contain the data thats in stick columns. I think it would work.

Comment: Buddy I am confused on how to use this. In your example, Are you assuming that "perfdepth1" member already exists in the class? and you are just populating the value?

Comment: No. You need to look up ExpandoObject  on msdn  for a good description. Basically it's an object that allows you to use it to dynamically add class members on the fly. Also take a look at anonymous classes. Both can be assigned to dynamic and both can be used to dynamically construct objects.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/