# Create Object and its Properties at Run-time from List

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, office-interop

I need to create dynamic object and its properties at run-time then create instance of this object to store values.

why I want above logic!

I am reading excel file in C# and first line of code is header which is actually  properties and followed by each rows are record which is instance of dynamic object.

```
 List<string> ExcelDataHeader = new List<string>();
         for (int y = 2; y <= colCount; y++)
           {
             ExcelDataHeader.Add(xlRange.Cells[headerRow, y].Value2.ToString());
           }

  dynamic MyDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    ??????????
```

I need to return excel read data in object

Comment: Usually you set the proerties by using `MyDynamic.PropertyName = value`. In your case `value` probably comes from the sheet, so it´s rather something like `MyDynamic.PropertyName = ExcelDataHeader[3]`. I don´t understand what your question is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically Add C# Properties at Runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime)

Comment: Why create a dynamic object? Just store your values in a `Dictionary`. Seems a lot simpler to me.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use `ExpandoObject` here - it'll work, but you need to use the dictionary API:

```
IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj["id"] = 123;
obj["name"] = "Fred";

// this is the "dynamic" bit:
dynamic dyn = obj;
int id = dyn.id; // 123
string name = dyn.name; // "Fred"
```

However, I fail to see the point. Since you won't be referring to the object in C# code by things like `obj.PropertyName`, `dynamic` has very little purpose. You might as well just store each record in a `Dictionary<string,object>` or similar. *Given what you describe*, there are no places where you would actually use `MyDynamic` as a `dynamic` object.