# Is it feasible to pass List from MVC controller to View though JSON without creating class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expandoobject

I am using Angular JS to create JSON from MVC Controller to View.
I passed it previously like this
Model

```
public class obj
{
    public string somestring {get;set;}
}
```

MVC controller

```
List<obj> lstObj=new List<obj>();
obj o = new obj();
o.somestring="somestring";
lstObj.Add(o);
IDictionary<string,object> dic=new Dictionary<string,object>();
dic.Add("data",lstObj);
return Json(dic);
```

in the view I get the Json as

```
{["somestring":"somestring"]}
```

But when I try the same code with  ExpandoObject
from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15819760) answer to [Dynamically Add C# Properties at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime/15819760#15819760)

```
List<dynamic> lstObj = new List<dynamic>();
var dynO = DataHelper.GetDynamicObject(new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        {"somestring","somestring"}
                    });
lstObj.Add(dynO);
IDictionary<string,object> dic=new Dictionary<string,object>();
dic.Add("data",lstObj);
return Json(dic);
```

it returns

```
{[]}
```

Is it feasible to obtain Json using ExpandoObject?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for spending your valuable time mates
I have overcome it by creating an object using new {}

```
List<dynamic> lstObj = new List<dynamic>();
var dynO =new
                    {somestring="somestring"}
                ;
lstObj.Add(dynO);
IDictionary<string,object> dic=new Dictionary<string,object>();
dic.Add("data",lstObj);
return Json(dic);
```

output is

```
{["somestring":"somestring"]}
```