# What does the star mean in function definition like "function* ()"?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, ecmascript-6

```
 function*() { .... }
```

I just found that form of definition in some other js code, what does the star mean indeed? Thanks

Comment: What or where is this "some other js code"?

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/1xpa6q/generator_functions_whats_the_difference_between/) answers your question?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22004108/1903116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3agenerators)

> A function with a * token is known as a generator function. The
>   following two unary operators are only allowed in the immediate body
>   of a generator function (i.e., in the body but not nested inside
>   another function):

```
AssignmentExpression:
    ...
    YieldExpression

YieldExpression:
    "yield" ("*"? AssignmentExpression)?
```

> An early error is raised if a yield or yield* expression occurs in a
>   non-generator function.

Also check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2a) and **[What Is This Thing Called Generators?](http://tobyho.com/2013/06/16/what-are-generators/)**

Answer (score 18):

In ES2015+, it defines a [*generator function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Here's an example of a generator:

```
function* fibonacci() {
    let [prev, curr] = [0, 1];
    while (true) {
        [prev, curr] = [curr, prev + curr];
        yield curr;
    }
}
```

Various ways to use:

With a `for-of` loop (another ES2015+ thing):

```
for (const n of fibonacci()) {
    // truncate the sequence at 1000
    if (n > 1000) {
        break;
    }
    console.log(n);
}
```

Example:

```js
function* fibonacci() {
    let [prev, curr] = [0, 1];
    while (true) {
        [prev, curr] = [curr, prev + curr];
        yield curr;
    }
}

for (const n of fibonacci()) {
    // truncate the sequence at 1000
    if (n > 1000) {
        break;
    }
    console.log(n);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Using the iterator directly (`for-of` uses it under the covers for you):

```
const seq = fibonacci();
console.log(seq.next().value); // 1
console.log(seq.next().value); // 2
console.log(seq.next().value); // 3
console.log(seq.next().value); // 5
console.log(seq.next().value); // 8
```

```js
function* fibonacci() {
    let [prev, curr] = [0, 1];
    while (true) {
        [prev, curr] = [curr, prev + curr];
        yield curr;
    }
}

const seq = fibonacci();
console.log(seq.next().value); // 1
console.log(seq.next().value); // 2
console.log(seq.next().value); // 3
console.log(seq.next().value); // 5
console.log(seq.next().value); // 8
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Oh, an ES6 feature. Sweet.