# What does star (*) mean in JavaScript function definition in Koa framework?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, koa

I have been familiarising myself with Koa (http://koajs.com/). Many of the examples include star character in place of function name. For instance in the hello world example there is:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(function *(){
  this.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

What does this star mean?

Comment: It's generator function. Check similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23285200/1140227

Comment: http://h3manth.com/new/blog/2014/getting-started-with-koajs/   Gives a nice explanation, it's called harmony:generators

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It generally creates an "iterator" so you can yield result's one at a time.

Similar to C#'s [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) key work.

#### Official Information

**Example**

The “infinite” sequence of Fibonacci numbers (notwithstanding behavior around 2^53):

```
function* fibonacci() {
    let [prev, curr] = [0, 1];
    for (;;) {
        [prev, curr] = [curr, prev + curr];
        yield curr;
    }
}
```

Generators can be iterated over in loops:

```
for (n of fibonacci()) {
    // truncate the sequence at 1000
    if (n > 1000)
        break;


  print(n);
}
```

Generators are iterators:

```
let seq = fibonacci();
print(seq.next()); // 1
print(seq.next()); // 2
print(seq.next()); // 3
print(seq.next()); // 5
print(seq.next()); // 8
```

Comment: Hey that's kinda cool

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Would you happen to know by any chance why the syntax is `*`? E.g. what is the reason you need to explicitly define that something is a generator? For instance in Python you don't need to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea..

Comment: While this is a 100% valid answer, still not clear what are generators used for in this very piece of code - why exactly do we need generator to assign this.body = 'Hello World?';

Comment: In Python I believe the presence of the "yield" operator is what determines if you have created a function or a generator. In Javascript this is explicit.

Comment: There's a good summary of Koa's use of generators at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/12/21/experiments-with-koa-and-javascript-generators/