# Pointers in JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

This function in typescript

```js
async function main() {
```

is converted to

```js
function main() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
```

Does that `*` in `function*` represent a C++ like pointer ?

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620586/what-is-function-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620586/what-is-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `function*` declaration (function keyword followed by an asterisk) defines a generator function, which returns a Generator object.

Refer to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)