# How do I return results while inside a loop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Essentially, I have a `Do..While` loop going through some lines from a text file.  I want to process a line, return a value (worked or didn't), then move to the next line.

I have a function called `ProcessTXT` that accepts 2 strings.  `Source` and `Destination` of new file.

Is there a way to set a `ReturnedValue string =` to the result and have the backgroundworker check to see if the variable changed?  And if so, add this value to the list box?

```
private void TranslatePOD(string strSource, string strDest,)
{
  TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(strDest);
  TextReader tr = new StreamReader(strSource);
  do
    {
      //My Code doing stuff
      //Need to send a result somehow now, but i have more work to do in this loop
      //Then using tw.writeline() to write my results to my new file
    } while (tr.ReadLine() != null);
}
```

EDIT:  Current test code using Yield.  My output is "TestingGround.Form1+d__0".  Did i do something wrong?

```
namespace TestingGround
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static IEnumerable<string> TestYield(string strSource) 
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(strSource);
        string strCurLine = System.String.Empty;

        while ((strCurLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return strCurLine;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MySource = System.String.Empty;
        MySource = @"C:\PODTest\Export Script\Export\Shipment List.csv";
        listBox1.Items.Add(TestYield(MySource));

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of your code? What are you trying to accomplish? There are several methods for copying/parsing a file...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270086/what-is-the-use-of-the-yield-keyword-in-c

Comment: Well, i am taking an Export CSV from one system, converting to the way our customer needs it, then saving it as ACSII text..  So i need to analyze each line to make sure it is in the correct format, move data around, etc..

Comment: Maybe make a function that processes one line at a time, or call a method that handles your results, you could do this asynchronously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/9k7k7cf0.ASPX) is typically used to return results iteratively, or streaming.  There are plenty of examples online.  There's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271225/c-sharp-reading-a-file-line-by-line) on SO for reading in a file.

Comment: Yield does not address the cross-thread aspect of the question.

Comment: @EricJ. - No argument there, though I don't see any particular reason to use a backgroundworker clearly explained in the question so that's the best I can do at this point.  Yield gets at the core of the question.  Stopping to perform work.

Comment: I am looking at your link now. I think I get what Yield is doing.  But isnt essentially just taking all of the results and giving them at the end?  That may be enough for me.  But if i read this right, i dont think this is what i am looking for.

Comment: @Shifty - It doesn't give the results "at the end".  It temporarily returns control back to the caller.  It works with enumerations (iterating), giving you the power to perform work before "popping the next item off the stack", if you will.  It may help to run it through a debugger and see for yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I will debug a few examples to see how it works.  Sorry, rather new to C# if you couldnt tell.

Comment: +1 for not addressing the cross-thread aspect! (Much better to stay on one thread unless you've a good reason not to).

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - This thing is making me feel dumb.  I am looking at the examples in your link from SO.  I am not getting any compile errors, but it isnt returning what i expected it to.  Sorry, added new code to the original question.

Comment: @Shifty - yield works with an iterator.  Add a forach loop around the listbox.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - Just did that... Realized that as I posted the last one...  It seems to be returning like it wanted!  Now the only questions is, does this work like DoEvents did in VB6?  If i was working with a file that had 2000 lines or more, would the program appear locked out? or would the GUI update with the yield?  Thanks again.

Comment: Long running processes will block the UI.  Still need to use typical new thread solution.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - Gotcha.  But this seems to fit the bill so far.  I just needed to get the results while i was in the loop, and this is doing it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is a good case for a producer/consumer queue.  C# 4.0 introduced `BlockingCollection`, which is great for this.  Create the blocking collection and ensure that both this process, and whatever needs to consume the results you are passing have access to it.  This method can add items to the queue, and whatever is reading the results can use the `Take` method, which will block [wait] until there is at least one item to take out.  The collection is specifically designed to work in multithreaded environments; all of the operations are logically atomic.

Comment: Taking a look at this now.  Thanks Servy.